# ngDraggable avoid ng-click after drag end

Tags: angularjs, draggable, angularjs-ng-click

i have ng-click on the ng-drag element, when i am starting to move the element it's everything ok, but when i stop it, that element activate my ng-click, how can i avoid that ng-click?

```
<div ng-click="unselectImage(image);" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="'multipleItems'" ng-center-anchor="true" data-allow-transform="false" ng-drag-success="selectImage(image);"></div>
```

I am using [ngDraggable](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable). I tried to use `ng-drag-success` without success.

Comment: Try the `ng-drop-success`?

Comment: ng-drag-success do the job, but it's not working on most of the cases. And generally i  believe there are way of tell to not use ng-click if we are dragging.

Comment: You probably need to wait for an answer [here](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/issues/188) or you could try to implement something similar as mentioned [here](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/issues/50)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i did, with help of David Zemens. i figure it out that i can use

```
$rootScope.$on('draggable:start', function (data) {
    isDragging=true;
});
```

and inside my ng-click function i add something like this:

```
$scope.unselectImage = function (image) {
    if(isDragging) isDragging=false;
    else{
        // do the magic
    }
}
```

and generally it do the trick. When drag start, it broadcast that it is starting, and when it end's ng-click work out, in our case it simply say that drag is over.

Comment: Actually i made it this way and it working perfectly, forget to answer this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I made a directive ([alClick](https://github.com/maaljam/alClick)) which is merely ng-click but cancels any click if the press duration is longer than 750ms by default. Therefore, no click or tap event will fire when dragging or swiping.

```
<div al-click="unselectImage(image);" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="'multipleItems'" ng-center-anchor="true" data-allow-transform="false" ng-drag-success="selectImage(image);"></div>
```

Comment: That's the way to do it - answer is complete & customized to the question.

Comment: Nice directive!  For a desktop setting, I wonder if, instead of just considering if it should click based on time, it could also consider based on pixels moved?  I can do a 'quick drag' that still triggers a click.  It seems that that is not yet supported, but I haven't looked through the code base.